# Reiniciar corriente de Arduino cuando hay un error

Tags: c++, arduino

hay una forma de reiniciar o bloquear la corriente cuando tengo un error en arduino.

Ejemplo: Uso un sensor, si funciona bien, pero el serial dice que no reconoce los datos enviados del sensor. Hay una forma de reiniciar la corriente o bloquearla por un rato?

Answer (score 0):

En Arduino sólo puedes controlar el nivel de voltaje (0v/5v) en los pines configurados de salida (OUTPUT). La corriente (el amperaje) se ajusta de acuerdo con la impedancia del circuito/sensor conectado al pin: I = V * R.

Los pines configurados de entrada tiene el voltaje que determine el circuito al que están conectados. En modo INPUT, los pines son de alta impedancia (mínima corriente).

Si un sensor falla, tu única opción es ignorar sus señales y detener la operación, pues supuestamente el sensor es parte vital del circuito.

Este es un código real. Lee la temperatura de un DS18D20. Si el sensor falla (devuelve un `nan` como temperatura), el código aborta el proceso:

```
/*
   Obtiene la temperatura en grados celsius
*/
float readTemp()
{
  float t = 0;

  sensor.setWaitForConversion(true);
  sensor.requestTemperatures();
  t = sensor.getTempCByIndex(0);
 
  if (isnan(t) || t < -20) {
    Serial.println("---");
    Serial.println("Falla en el sensor de temperatura");
    abort();  # Apaga todo.
  }

  return t;
}
```